# error: control may reach end of non-void function in Luhn's alghoritm

Tags: c, cs50, luhn

```
bool if_valid(long n) //Implementing the Luhn's alghoritm
{
    int odd = 0;//Will take the sum of the numbers in the 1,3,5,7... th digits
    int even = 0;//Will take the sum of the numbers in the 2,4,6,8... th digits
    for(int k = 1; (n / 10) >= 1; k ++)//My main idea is, take the modulo 10 of the number, subtract 
    the remainder from the number and divide the number by 10.
    {
        if (k % 2 == 1)
        {
            int r = n % 10;//Remainder
            odd += r;
            n -= r;
            n /= 10;//Number's digit is increased
        }
        else
        {
            int r = n % 10;
            n -= r;
            n /= 10;
            r *= 2;
            if(r >= 10)
            {
                even += r % 10;
                r -= r % 10;
                r /= 10;
                even += r % 10;
            
            }
            else
            {
                even += r % 10;
            }
        }
        even = even + odd;
        if(even % 10 == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I was trying yo check if a credit card number is valid or not. I am getting control may reach end of non-void function error but as i am a fresh c coder i didn't understand why my function isn't working. Could you please help me?

Comment: Aside: if you stop thinking "number --> integer!" and pick the digits out of a string the job will be much easier.

Comment: The compiler message is because when the loop (and function) ends there is no `return X` statement. I think you need to move the next-to-last brace up 9 lines so that it is above `even = even + odd`. So that those statements are outside the loop. In side the loop as they are, you have not finished summing the odd and even position digits.